# MoshiConverterFactory is not accessable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I have added both dependencies for `Moshi` and `converter-Moshi` but yet `MoshiConverterFactory` is not accessible and prompting error. Why am I facing this error? I tried to use scalar-converter which worked perfectly but moshi-converter is not.

I have attached the photo of the code where red text clearly shows that `converter` is not imported.

```
    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    // Retrofit with Moshi Converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.3'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
```

```
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory


private val BASE_URL = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    //here MoshiConverterFactory showing errors
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the main Moshi dependency. You have added the Kotlin specific dependency, but the main Moshi still is missing. Try adding that and try again.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0'
```

Comment: This is not working for me still.
//network
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$moshi"
    implementation  "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiConvertor"

Answer (score 4):

You Must make sure that you have added all dependencies

```
//moshi
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.14.0'
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.14.0"

//retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")`
```